# Object type is lost in message passing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I'm working on a Chrome extension and I've the following problem.
When a certain event happens, my *background page* creates a new tab (page) with `chrome.tabs.create` API  and send an Object.

The sent Object (called items) is a list of objects, having a particular class (prototype) called Item.

Here some code:

```
// in background.html
chrome.tabs.create({index: 0, url: "results.html"}, function(tab) {
     chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {'items': itemsList}, function(response) {
         console.log(response.farewall);
     });
});
```

On the other hand, in the newly created page, I receive the sent objects

```
// newpage.html
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.dir(request.items);
        sendResponse({});
    }                   
);
```

The problem is that, when I receive the objects list, in the `newpage.html`, the Object    type is lost. Indeed using `console.dir()` in the new `background page`, the objects type in the **itemsList** is correctly reported, but not in the received items list object in `newpage.html`.

I could manually serialize the data in he `background.html` manually through a string, and manually de-serialize in `newpage.html` but I would like to know if there is a better way to afford this and prevent that objects type (namely Item) in the list is lost.

Comment: if `itemsList` is already a json object, why dont you just pass object without the `'items'` key? thats the way I usually do it and i can access the object items directly on the receiving end with `request.item_name`...  maybe i misunderstand what your asking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When passing an object through a request, Chrome requires it to be "JSON-serializable", which hints that it is encoded to JSON string before the transfer, transferred as a string, and then decoded back. And JSON doesn't support function serialization.